# How to change list settings globally?

Tags: lists, enumitem, obsolete

I'm new to latex, so this might just be a stupid error on my end, but I've downloaded the `enumitem` package and am trying to globally change the style of `{enumerate}` so that I don't have to type

`\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),itemsep=3pt,topsep=3pt]`

every time I want to make a list. I've tried doing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\listfiles
\setlist[enumerate]{label=(\roman*),itemsep=3pt,topsep=3pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item one
\item two
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

but this doesn't change anything. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: version: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)`

EDIT: the information from `\listfiles` is as follows:

```
*File List*
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
enumitem.sty    2009/05/18 v2.2 Customized lists
keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
***********
```

EDIT: sorry for all these edits. I keep compiling my MWE and getting no change from the classic `enumerate` style, but if I try to change the enumerate style each time I use `\begin{enumerate}`, it changes the way I want it to. I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using TeXShop version 2.47.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I edited it, is that enough for a MWE?

Comment: Your MWE produces the desired result on my machine. What exactly do you get with your example code?

Comment: It produces: 1. one 2. two, just like the normal `enumerate` style, but when I change the enumerate style as I'm making the list, i.e. `\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*),itemsep=3pt,topsep=3pt]`, I get my desired result. Is there some sort of problem with the rest of my preamble? I can post that too, it's not that long.

Comment: Check whether your LaTeX compiler signals some errors.

Comment: I second egreg. Also, when you're testing/debugging, you should actually be compiling your MWE, not the real document. The entire point of a MWE is to help debugging and concentrate on the relevant parts.

Comment: I am compiling my MWE and getting the same problem. I get no errors from my LaTeX compiler.

Comment: What version and LaTeX distribution are you using? Perhaps you have outdated packages?

Comment: using TeXShop version 2.47, just downloaded `enumitem` today

Comment: @user19610 Put `\listfiles` in your MWE's preamble, this will print information about the files used in your log file. Edit this information into your question. Also, your log should start with something like `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2012.6.15)  1 OCT 2012 15:06` -- this is the information Gonzalo was looking for.

Comment: @user19610 +1 for adding an MWE on request. :-)

Comment: Sorry!! okay @gonzalomedina, here's what you wanted: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.11 (TeX Live 2010)` and @doncherry, I've edited my question again

Comment: After adding `\listfiles` to the preamble of the example code and processing the file, your `.log` file contains a section `*File List*` with information about the packages and their versions; please add this information to your question.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina sorry for all the hassle. question edited.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Version 2.2 of `enumitem` used a different way to setup the standard lists; for your needs it should be

```
\setenumerate{label=(\roman*),itemsep=3pt,topsep=3pt}
```

If you downloaded the last version, you probably haven't put it in a place where the TeX system can find it and it uses the default one; I guess you installed the TeX distribution with MacTeX that always does a full installation.

If you want to use the last version, you need to properly install it, but beware that it may break. The best thing you can do is to update MacTeX to version 2012 (and run TeX Live Utility afterwards) that will bring the TeX distribution to the current state.

However, your setting is in any case not the best one, as LaTeX would use lowercase roman numbers for all enumerate levels. You should better say

```
\setenumerate{itemsep=3pt,topsep=3pt}
\setenumerate[1]{label=(\roman*)}
```

for `enumitem` version 2.2 or

```
\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=3pt,topsep=3pt}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=(\roman*)}
```

for the current version. In this way the spacing parameters are used for every level, but roman numbers only for the first one.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm sorry my unfamiliarity with LaTeX made my question confusing, but thank you for helping me through it! I think I must have only downloaded verison 2.2 of enumitem. For the document I need (review sheet for an exam), I only need one level for enumerate, so your first suggestion suffices, but I see your point and put in the second (better) suggestion. Thank you!