# \setlabelphantom for whole document

Tags: labels, description

I am having a document with several descriptions. Some of the labels are too long for the default length, so I use `\setlabelphantom{word}` for setting this to a custom length. Does anyone of you know how to set the label-phantom for the entire document? So that I am having it consistent and always long enough.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{expdlist}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}[\setlabelphantom{long-label~}]
    \item[long-label] text1 
    \item[long-label] text2
\end{description}
\begin{description}[\setlabelphantom{label~}]
    \item[label] text1 
    \item[label] text2
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can globally set options for lists using the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{expdlist}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{labelwidth=2cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[long-label] text1 
    \item[long-label] text2
\end{description}
\begin{description}
    \item[label] text1 
    \item[label] text2
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Source (among others): [How to change list settings globally?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75578/how-to-change-list-settings-globally)

Edit: if you want to specify a phantom-like label width you can use `\widthof` from the `calc` package:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlist[description]{labelwidth=\widthof{long-label~}}
```